# CSS transition not working inside react loop when updating on click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a list of cards moving in the horizontal direction using css `transform 1.45s ease-out` while clicking. This is my cards component

```
<CardList transition={this.state.transition} translateValue={this.state.translateValue} arrayOfCards={this.state.arrayOfCards} handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
```

Here i iterate through list of cards

```
function CardList(props) {
            const cards = props.arrayOfCards;
            const handleClick = props.handleClick;
            const translateValue = props.translateValue;
            const transition = props.transition;
            const cardList = cards.map(function(card, index) {
                return (<div className="cards-container" key={index} onClick={handleClick} style={{padding: '20px', transform: `translateX(${translateValue}px)`, transition: `${transition}`}}>
                    <Card style={{ width: 170, height: 200 }}>
                        <p>Card content {card}</p>
                    </Card>
                </div>);
            });
            return cardList;
        }
```

On handleClick i updating the transition and transform value like this.

```
handleClick() {
    let cards = this.state.arrayOfCards;
    //arrayOfCards logic goes here
    this.setState({
        arrayOfCards: arrayOfCards,
        translateValue: -210,
        transition: 'transform 1.45s ease-out'
    });
}
```

I dont know why the css is not working inside loop. Please help me.